# Preventing Evaluation of Body of Manipulate

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate, evaluation, dynamic, conditional

Overall, I am looking for a way to prevent the evaluation of the body of `Manipulate` until the controls meet a certain condition.

For example, consider the following.

```
Manipulate[
 
(*big code*),
 
 {{x, Null}, {1, 2}, PopupMenu},
 {{y, Null}, {3, 4}, PopupMenu},
 TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

`(* big code*)` depends on `x` and `y` and is not just one function, but large, computationally expensive code containing variable assignments and functions. Because the body of `Manipulate` is computationally expensive, I of course, do not want it to run if either `x` is Null or `y` is Null.

---

I tried using `If` and `SynchronousUpdating -> True` as below.

```
Manipulate[
 
 If[x == Null || y == Null, {x, y}, #] &@(* big code*),
 
 {{x, Null}, {1, 2}, PopupMenu},
 {{y, Null}, {3, 4}, PopupMenu},
 TrackedSymbols :> True, SynchronousUpdating -> True]
```

However, something is fishy here. First, when running the code for the first time, `x` and `y` are both Null, so the code should run very fast. I get the correct output, but the code is slow, which makes me think `(* big code*)` is still being read when it shouldn't be. Second, if I then change `x` while keeping `y` in its default Null value, I get the correct output, but once again, the code runs slowly. Finally, when I make both `x` and `y` not Null, the output is garbled.

I feel there should be a better way of doing what I want anyway. Any thoughts?

I just want the body of `Manipulate` to be touched in no way until the controls meet a certain condition.

---

### Update

Doing all of what @lericr mentioned in the comments solves this problem.

Comment: can you modify the definition of `expensiveFunct` to only fire on numbers?  Something like `expensiveFunct[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := <expensive code>; expensiveFunct[___] := $Failed`

Comment: @JasonB I have undated my post. To be clear, it isn't one function. It is a large chunk of code containing many functions and variable assignment.

Comment: `If` is a special form. It holds its arguments (after the initial predicate) unevaluated. But you're applying a functional form (`If[...,...,#]&`), so the `big code` stuff is being evaluated. You need to put the `big code` stuff inside the `If`. Another problem is you're using `==` with `Null`, which I don't think will ever evaluate to a boolean unless the left hand side is `Null`. So, you either need to use `===` or you need to add a fourth argument to your `If`.

Comment: As an illustration of @lericr 's comment compare `a = 1; If[a == 1, 1, Pause[2]] // AbsoluteTiming` with `a = 1; If[a == 1, 1, #] &[Pause[2]] // AbsoluteTiming`. However `If[a == 1, 1, #; 2] &[Unevaluated[Pause[2]]] // AbsoluteTiming` leads to the same result as placing the `Pause` inside the `If`

Comment: For the Null part one may compare : `a = 1; If[a == Null, 1, 2]` with `a = 1; If[a === Null, 1, 2]`

Comment: Not sure if you can maybe `Iconize` the big code to make the code look nicer after copy pasting it into `If`.

Comment: It is unclear to me why you can not wrap the whole code into a function as JasonB suggested regardless of whether there are function definitions inside of the code.

Comment: Thanks to @lericr and all others. These comments solved my problem.

Comment: I simulate the large part by Print["a"]. Then `Manipulate[(If[(x =!= Null) && ( y =!= Null), Print["a"]]; {x, 
   y}), {{x, Null}, {1, 2}, PopupMenu}, {{y, Null}, {3, 4}, 
  PopupMenu}, TrackedSymbols :> {x, y}]`